# Does pthread_mutex_lock have happens-before semantics

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, happens-before

threadA go through this snippet

```
{
    global_a = 100;  // 1
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&b_mutex)
                ...
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&b_mutex)
    }  // 2
}
```

threadB go through this snippet

```
{
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&b_mutex)
                ...
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&b_mutex)
    }  // 3

    int tmp = global_a; // 4
}
```

and suppose that from an observer view the execution sequence indeed is

1. threadA --- 1
2. threadA --- 2
3. threadB --- 3
4. threadB --- 4

Can the code at threadB `"int tmp = global_a;"` see what threadA set at `"global_a = 100;"`?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_mutex_lock` does not prevent *previous* instructions to be ordered after it.

Similar, `pthread_mutex_unlock` does not prevent *followed* instructions to be ordered before it.

But:

1. In threadA `global_a = 100` *happens-before* `pthread_mutex_unlock(&b_mutex)`.
2. In threadB `pthread_mutex_lock(&b_mutex)` *happens-before* `int tmp = global_a;`.

And if you observe

3. `pthread_mutex_unlock(&b_mutex)` in threadA *happens-before* `pthread_mutex_lock(&b_mutex)` in threadB.

(in other words, threadB aquires lock *after* threadA releases it), then

`global_a = 100;` in threadA *happens-before* `int tmp = global_a;` in threadB. So, the last one sees effect of the first one.

**What POSIX Standard says:**

As for synchronisation details in the POSIX standard, the only reference I found (and others refer to) is short chapter about [Memory Synchronization](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11). It says that `pthread_mutex_lock` (and some other functions)

> synchronize memory with respect to other threads

Someones interpret this as **full memory barrier** garantee, others (and me) prefer to think about some *classic* garantees, when locking and waiting actions provides *memory acquire* semantic, unlocking and notifying ones - *memory release* semantic. See, e.g., this [mail](http://www.decadent.org.uk/pipermail/cpp-threads/2005-May/000436.html).

There is no *happens-before* term in the POSIX. But it can be defined as usual, taking into account memory order garantees(in one's inerpretation).

Comment: The proof is great, But where is the definition of **happens-before** and the **transitiviy** by **happens-before** with `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`? I had google it but nothing. Can you show me some reference about it?

Comment: I have added some references into my answer. POSIX doesn't define *happens-before* term, but it can be defined according to memory order garantees.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee the execution sequence - when yes. If you can guarantee the execution sequence you do not need even a lock on some architectures.

Lock actually do three things:
1. Do not allow different code to be executed same time. See. There is no mention of the memory here. It just guarantee that code in different threads will not be executed same time.
2. On some architecture it will insert cache coherence instructions. Which force multiple processor systems to flush data into the real memory. But you should not worry about this case cause right now "a multiprocessor is cache consistent if all writes to the same memory location are performed in some sequential order"
3. It insert memory barrier instruction. It is for processor, tell it do not mess with execution order.

Also you compiler may brake things as well. So declare your variable as volatile.

Comment: At the end with "So declare your variable as volatile.",  Do you mean maybe threadB "int tmp = global_a;"  **cannot** see what threadA set at "global_a = 100;"